# Creating XML file from HTML form

Tags: php, xml, forms

Ok so I got it working, now the only problem is when a new submission is added it overwrites the previous entry. I need it to add the newest submission to the XML file and not over ride it and store it for X amount of time.

Here is the working php script that creates the xml file and takes the data from the HTML form and puts it in the XML file.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['lsr-submit']))
    {
        header('Location: http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxmesqLSR.php');
    }

$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entrys></entrys>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$report = $_POST['report'];
$description = $_POST['desc'];

$fname = htmlentities($fname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$lname = htmlentities($lname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$location = htmlentities($location, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$report = htmlentities($report, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$description = htmlentities($description, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);

$xml->reports = "";
$xml->reports->addChild('fname', $fname);
$xml->reports->addChild('lname', $lname);
$xml->reports->addChild('location', $location);
$xml->reports->addChild('report', $report);
$xml->reports->addChild('description', $description);

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->loadXML($xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$doc->save('test2.xml');

?>
```

Here is the xml file it creates.

[XML FILE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/test2.xml)

Here is the form to submit to the XML file. Submit a test submission and it takes you to the page to display but you'll notice it will overwrite the last one instead of adding to the XML file.

[HTML FORM](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxmesqLSR-report.php)

Comment: you could research using the DOM http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

Comment: For the `X amount of time`, you'll probably need a `cron` job for this.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135467/saving-form-data-to-an-existing-xml-file-using-php

Comment: and this link http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-SimpleXML-With-PHP.html - lots of helpful info in there.

Comment: See my edited post. I tried the example from that one link but it shows nothing. The second link I already know. I need to produce a XML file from a HTML form.

Comment: @Texan78 I'm getting somewhere with info from http://www.molecularsciences.org/book/export/html/301

Comment: @Texan78 I have something working but can't figure out how to add new entries to it. It keeps overwriting with the new content. If you can find that out, would be really cool.

Comment: It's a good article and creates an XML file but how to you submit the info from the form into that file? I have updated my original post with what I am testing and working with.

Comment: @Texan78 I can't for the life of me, figure out how to add childs to it. I can post a rough and pure PHP version to add to a file, but am not 100% sure it's what you'd want. It's not THEE way to do it, but it works to a certain extent. It's the structure I'm not sure about, how it's supposed to follow suit. The script I made, the `<entry>` and `<reports>` repeat themselves.

Comment: Well I got the it to create the file and have add child elements but I have not been able to to get it post the data from the form to the XML file.

Comment: See my updated post. I have it working but with one small issue.

Comment: @Texan78 yeah saw that. Having the same problem too. One script runs fine, adds the info but only works for 1 field (first name). I'll get back to you, I really need some shut eye.

Comment: @Texan78 This one was a real `head banger`, and have something to post. Thing is, I'm not an `XML` guy and was a `learning curve` if anything. So if y'all still want to see what I've made, let me know Bro.

Comment: @Texan78 I noticed your other question about not using a hidden field for the timestamp. Figured it out with someone's example. I'm ready if you are.

Comment: I got the timestamp sorted out already and working perfectly. I am still stuck with adding submissions to the XML instead of overwriting them.

Comment: @Texan78 The solution I came up with, doesn't resemble your posted code and there's a slight problem with it/mine, being that if the file doesn't exist (.xml) will throw out an error.

Comment: I have working code that does exactly what I am needing it to do. Problem with it is I am unable to append data to that XML file upon further submissions from the form. It just overwrites the existing entry. I need to be able to append data from the form to the XML file and that is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: @Texan78 Check out my answer below. Keep me posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with and works well, and tested.

**NOTE**: However if the file (`file.xml`) does not exist, it will throw off an error, so if you figure out a way to automatically delete the old file(s) via `CRON` or any other method ***(you mentioned: "...and store it for X amount of time.")***, you'll have to come up with a way to make a pre-built structured file with at least one set of entries inside it.

E.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entries>
  <reports>
    <timestamp>May 31, 2013, 11:56 am</timestamp>
    <fname>Fred</fname>
    <lname>Fletcher</lname>
    <location>Canada</location>
    <report>Wind Damage</report>
    <description>Winds were gusting mighty hard today!</description>
  </reports>
</entries>
```

This is relatively easy to do, I've done it before with an `if file exists...`.

Here is my working code:

```
<?php

// Script by Fred Fletcher, Canada.

$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$report = $_POST['report'];
$description = $_POST['desc'];

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load('file.xml');

$element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('reports')->item(0);

$timestamp = $element->getElementsByTagName('timestamp')->item(0);
$fname = $element->getElementsByTagName('fname')->item(0);
$lname = $element->getElementsByTagName('lname')->item(0);
$location = $element->getElementsByTagName('location')->item(0);
$report = $element->getElementsByTagName('report')->item(0);
$description = $element->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0);

$newItem = $xml->createElement('reports');

$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('timestamp', date("F j, Y, g:i a",time())));;

$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('fname', $_POST['firstname']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('lname', $_POST['lastname']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('location', $_POST['location']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('report', $_POST['report']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('description', $_POST['desc']));

$xml->getElementsByTagName('entries')->item(0)->appendChild($newItem);

$xml->save('file.xml');

echo "Data has been written.";

?>
```

A "plug" as a comment in the script would be nice, "Script by Fred Fletcher, Canada." (wink)

Let me know how this works out for you.

Comment: Thanks, I copied it as is but it isn't working at all for me. Do I need to add that to my existing code? I don't need it to delete the entire file after X amount of time. I need it to delete entries from it after X amount of time. I am not sure if a Cron could do something like that.

Comment: @Texan78 No, it's `right out of the box`. Not to be added to your existing code. Yet, look at the comments in my answer on specific instructions in regards to the `.xml` file must exist with at least one set of entries.

Comment: @Texan78 To delete entries themselves after a certain amount of time, will ask for higher scripting/programming skills than mine.

Comment: Deleting entries isn't important right now. I can tweak that later. The file existed but there was no entry but the entries are entered from a form and there won't always be data. So it needs to be able to enter data which the script I had did, I just couldn't add data to it.

Comment: @Texan78 Notice that your original name for `entrys` was named `entries`. Thought I'd mention that, so check your form to modify it to match my script with the `$_POST` fields etc.

Comment: that was exactly what the problem was. It needed to be entrys instead of entries. Now I can move on to tweaking it to delete entries after certain amount of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got your question, but if you need to create a file that is unique for each submission then you cannot simply use echo, you must actually create a file.

Also if after submitting you redirect to another PHP file, how can you handle the data to write into the variables?

Example for creating a file:

```
<?php // testfile.php
$fh = fopen("testfile.xml", 'w') or die("Failed to create file"); 
$text = <<<_END
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
_END;
fwrite($fh, $text) or die("Could not write to file"); 
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: I don't need a unique file for each submission. I just need to create a single XML file that will add new submissions to it and and store those submissions in the XML file for X amount of time. Sorry, I know it's confusing, I am trying to explain it the best and easiest as I can. Once it creates the XML file, the page it redirects to is setup to read that XML file and display the data.

Comment: Well you have anyway yo use the fopen function and to just start writing at the end of the file, so it won't replace the text you already have. Also do not put the redirect at the top of your php file, but create a statement that will run once the fopen function has completed its work.

Comment: @DiegoPucci FYI: The `w` switch will overwrite any content, and I quote: `"w" (Write only. Opens and clears the contents of file; or creates a new file if it doesn't exist)`. You must use either `a` or `a+` in order to `append`.

Comment: @Fred Yes sure. I was just pointing to the right direction using fopen. I wrote the comment after having written the answer

Comment: @DiegoPucci I understand. However in working with `xml` files, it's indeed a `strange animal` and needs some special attention from what I've gathered. I haven't worked with them much, probably why I tend to shy away from them. (lol)