# Appending XML file with php

Tags: php, xml

I have a script that creates an XML file with data from a HTML form. It works great and the XML file is created and the form writes data to it. I am having a hard time appending data to the XML file though. Every time I submit new data from the form to the XML file it just overwrites the last one instead of just adding that data to it.

Here is the php script I am using to create and write the XML file from the form.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['lsr-submit']))
    {
        header('Location: http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxmesqLSR.php');
    }

$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entrys></entrys>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$report = $_POST['report'];
$description = $_POST['desc'];

$fname = htmlentities($fname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$lname = htmlentities($lname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$location = htmlentities($location, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$report = htmlentities($report, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$description = htmlentities($description, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);

$xml->reports = "";
$xml->reports->addChild('timestamp', date("D M jS g:i a",time()));
$xml->reports->addChild('fname', $fname);
$xml->reports->addChild('lname', $lname);
$xml->reports->addChild('location', $location);
$xml->reports->addChild('report', $report);
$xml->reports->addChild('description', $description);

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->loadXML($xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$doc->save('test2.xml');

?>
```

Here is the XML output

[XML FILE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/test2.xml)

HTML Form in case anyways wants to see the behavior.

[HTML FORM](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxmesqLSR-report.php)

-Thanks!

Comment: Well.... `$xml->reports = "";`... What do you think that does? `$report = $xml->addChild('reports'); $report->addChild('time...` seems to be what you want.

Comment: I suggest you rename your question's name to `How to add entries...` instead of `Append`. I think people are probably misled by it.

Comment: @Fred I know how to add entries. I got this code from a link you recommended. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135467/saving-form-data-to-an-existing-xml-file-using-php Which works great. BUT, I can only add one entry as the form just overwrites the entry and doesn't add to it.

Comment: @Wrikken If I don't have $xml->reports = ""; in the code it won't add anything to the XML file at all when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Texan78: Did you _try_ my suggested replacement?

Comment: @Wrikken yes, I tried it, it really didn't do anything different than what I already had. It worked the same just. I found a solution to what I am needing but, it needs some tweaking.

Comment: @Texan76: [huh, funny that, you must have some mighty strange home-grown PHP version according to this code](http://codepad.org/96T8OnJu)

Comment: I guess I do then and I am not the only one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135467/saving-form-data-to-an-existing-xml-file-using-php

Comment: So, someone posted bad code as an answer, the OP comments: _"  But it stil replaces the last submitted XML data (in data.xml) NOT adding to it. – khaansen Aug 27 '12 at 11:20""_ And you think: hey that's what I am going to use? And then you complain about the known bug/feature of that code? Well, I gave you a working code example illustrating the basics (mainly look at line 9 & 10 of the linked codepad code), if you choose to ignore it, well, I wish you all the best. I have no energy left today whip sense into people.

Comment: @Wrikken let me break it down for you. This question is a result of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847841/creating-xml-file-from-html-form/16867075?noredirect=1#comment24330868_16867075 because THAT question which I was recommended to didn't have a solution to that problem and I couldn't find one which is why I am asking THIS question. The code YOU suggested from above which I applied here to my code http://codepad.org/7PbLLrnS does the EXACT same thing as the code I posted in THIS OP. I followed YOUR suggestion. It doesn't work!

Comment: @Texan78: of course _that_ code fails, because you are not opening an existing file. [have a look at this example](http://codepad.org/ePBBl4mv), note the comments.

Comment: @Wrikken but if the XML file exists but it's empty it won't submit to the XML file. It will only submit if there is an existing entry.

Comment: Absence of prior `reports` nodes is not problem, but if the file exists, and you haven't defined the _'entrys'_ (sic) rootnode in there, well, you might have a problem. An xml file without a root node is not valid, it isn't an XML file. I would make sure it doesn't exist in that case, but if you can't prevent that: `$xml = false;if(file_exists('your.xml')) $xml = simplexml_load_file('your.xml'); /* $xml will be false if the file doesnt exist or does not contain valid xml*/ if(!$xml) $xml = simplexml_load_string('<entrys/>');`

Comment: @Wrikken are you referring to this? http://codepad.org/MK005rnD

Comment: @Texan78: yes, but you forgot to enable the `$doc->save('test3.xml');` string there in the middle.

Comment: @Wrikken well I had to tweak it a little bit as it was double posting but I think I got it tested and it seems to be working correctly. Now need to work on my next issue. Hope this is correct. http://codepad.org/mIetWse5

Comment: Yeah, it was storing values twice, as it was a test-script designed to show appending rather then replacing, and we started out with an empty file. Nice it is resolved now, best of luck to you.