# DOMDocument error when trying to save date in xml file - php script

Tags: php, xml

Having a little problem with saving form data to xml. I've tried adding new element ($ukey) to xml object, but it gives me an error on line with $ukey variable.     $newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('ukey', $ukey));

```
// Script by Fred Fletcher, Canada.
$fname = $_POST['name'];
$lname = $_POST['email'];
$location = $_POST['cat'];
$report = $phone;
$description = $_POST['content'];
$ukey = date("dmYHis");


$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load('/home/mysite/public_html/file.xml');

$element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('reports')->item(0);

$timestamp = $element->getElementsByTagName('timestamp')->item(0);
$fname = $element->getElementsByTagName('fname')->item(0);
$lname = $element->getElementsByTagName('lname')->item(0);
$location = $element->getElementsByTagName('location')->item(0);
$report = $element->getElementsByTagName('report')->item(0);
$description = $element->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0);
$ukey = $element->getElementsByTagName('ukey')->item(0);

$newItem = $xml->createElement('reports');

$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('timestamp', date("F j, Y, g:i a",time())));;

$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('fname', $_POST['name']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('lname', $_POST['email']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('location', $_POST['cat']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('report', $phone));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('description', $_POST['content']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('ukey', $ukey));

$xml->getElementsByTagName('entries')->item(0)->appendChild($newItem);

$xml->save('/home/mysite/public_html/file.xml');
```

Here is the error

```
Warning: DOMDocument::createElement() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/myform.php on line 214

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given, called in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php on line 47 and defined in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/myform.php on line 214
```

And xml sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entries>
  <reports>
   <timestamp>September 19, 2013, 11:45 am</timestamp>
   <fname>John Snider</fname>
   <lname>mailATemail.com</lname>
   <location>156</location>
   <report>08974545153</report>
   <description>jhsdhfsdfgsdtasrgsfgasf</description>
   <ukey>156152</ukey>
  </reports>
</entries>
```

Do I need to change it to string or what is the problem?

Just to clarify, script was working great before I added $ukey

Thanks

Comment: I can only think that you should check that `$ukey = $element->getElementsByTagName('ukey')->item(0);` this line is returning something you expect. What is the value of $ukey at this point - perhaps use `isset($ukey)` before attempting to add to the newItem

Comment: Well, the value at this point should be date("dmYHis"). I think...

Comment: Do a `print_r()` to find out whether it really is that.

Comment: There is also this error below that warning. Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given, called in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php on line 47 and defined in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/myform.php on line 214

Comment: *"Do I need to change it to string or what is the problem?"* - The problem is that you use an object as string. Fix the warning first. Also: *"script was working great before I added $ukey"* - Just revert the change to get it working again. Then create a test-case from scratch, do the changes in the test-case until it works and then change the original script.

Comment: Big benefit if you don't get the test-case to work: As you have programmed it as reduced example, it's easier to ask about here a programming (not a code-dump) question.

Comment: And if you have a problem with a code by Fred Fletcher, why not discuss it with him? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16867075/367456 - Keep asking questions to your code, not third-party code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ukey = date("dmYHis");
```

Yes, that should be a nice string value containing a formatted date, fine.

```
$ukey = $element->getElementsByTagName('ukey')->item(0);
```

Oops, what are you doing here …?

```
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('ukey', $ukey));
```

Now, $ukey is not a string value any more, because of the line quoted before – you messed up with your variable names, dude.

Comment: Thanks for help. I was just following the logic of this script template I used - not really proficient in php. Could you please tell me what should I change? It would also useful for people who find this thread later on. Thanks again

Comment: Just rename one of the variables (of course at the points where you use it later on too), to avoid the collision. (And I doubt this is helpful for later readers, because it’s a combination of very spcific code and too little knowldge of the basics, sorry.)