# I would like to be able to edit the xml header tag

Tags: php, xml

following this post  [Saving form data to an existing XML-file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135467/saving-form-data-to-an-existing-xml-file-using-php)

i would like to know how can i save multiple variables into the xml file. using the method described i can only save the last one.

i found a method working as I want

```
$xml="\n\t\t<Bares>\n\t\t";     
    {
        while ($stmt->fetch()){ 

                $xml .="<Bar>\n\t\t";
                $xml .= "<nome>".$nome."</nome>\n\t\t";
                $xml .= "<morada>".$morada."</morada>\n\t\t";
                $xml .= "<nif>".$nif."</nif>\n\t\t";
                $xml .= "<telefone>".$telefone."</telefone>\n\t\t";
                $xml .= "<email>".$email."</email>\n\t\t";
                $xml .= "<imgid>".$imgid."</imgid>\n\t\t";
                $xml.="</Bar>\n\t";

        }

            $xml.="</Bares>\n\r";

            $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
            $doc->formatOutput = true;
            $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
            $doc->loadXML($xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
            $doc->save('dados.xml');
```

but i would like to be able to edit the xml header tag (xml version="1.0"?) and i cant do it this way

Comment: Why are you not using DOMDocument's [createElement()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) and [appendChild()](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) methods?

Comment: Because that way i couldn't save all the elements in the xml document, only the last one was saved. this is what i had:
`$xml->bar = "";
    $xml->bar->addChild('nome_bar', $nome);
    $xml->bar->addChild('morada_bar', $morada);
    $xml->bar->addChild('nif_bar', $nif);
    $xml->bar->addChild('telefone_bar', $telefone);
    $xml->bar->addChild('email_bar', $email);
    $xml->bar->addChild('imageId', $imgid);
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
    $doc->loadXML($xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
    $doc->save('dados.xml');`

Comment: That's because you do not iteratively add `<Bar>` as child to root `<Bares>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider again using [DOMDocument()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) methods instead of building XML with string concatenation. Using PHP's informative manuals, below shows how to add a [Document Type Declaration (DTD)](http://php.net/manual/en/domimplementation.createdocumenttype.php) and [XSLT processing line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createprocessinginstruction.php):

```
// Create an instance of the DOMImplementation class
$imp = new DOMImplementation;    
// Create a DOMDocumentType instance
$dtd = $imp->createDocumentType('graph', '', 'graph.dtd');

// Create a DOMDocument instance
$doc = $imp->createDocument();    
// Set other properties
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8'; $doc->standalone = true;
$doc->formatOutput = true; $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;

// Create an XSLT adding processing line
$xslt = $doc->createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 
                                          'type="text/xsl" href="base.xsl"');    
// Append XSLT instruction to the doc
$doc->appendChild($xslt);
// Append DTD to the doc
$doc->appendChild($dtd);

// Create root
$root = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('Bares'));

// Iteratively append the elements (with values)
while ($stmt->fetch()){                        
    $barNode = $root->appendChild($doc->createElement('bare'));
    $nomeNode = $barNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('nom', $nome));
    $moradaNode = $barNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('morada', $morada));                
    $nifNode = $barNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('nif', $nif));
    $telefoneNode = $barNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('telefone', $telefone));
    $emailNode = $barNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('email', $email));
    $imgidNode = $barNode->appendChild($doc->createElement('imgid', $imgid));          
}

$doc->save('dados.xml');
```